# Discrete time Pure-Birth process with population fraction

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, recurrence-relations, markov-process, polya-urn-model

I would like to solve difference equations for a pure-birth process, where the rate of adding new nodes depends on the fraction of population.

$$x_i(t+1)-x_i(t)=\alpha \frac{x_i(t)}{\sum{x_j(t)}}+\beta_i \frac{x_{i-1}(t)}{\sum{x_j(t)}}$$

where $x_i$ is the population of species of kind $i$ therefore $\frac{x_i(t)}{\sum{x_j(t)}}$ represents the fraction of population at time $t$.

What I am interested in is to find a closed form solution for $x_i(t)$.

I can see a resemblance to Urn model but wasn't able to find an explicit method for solving Urn model as difference/differential equations.

I would appreciate it, if you could guide me on how to find a closed form solution for this problem or introduce references.

EDIT: $i \in [0,1,...,L]$ where $L$ is a parameter of the model. 
I can assume either $x_{-1}=0$ or $x_{-1}=x_{L}$ whichever simplifies the set of equations.

Comment: What is the range on $i$? It seems like it would be unbounded below, from what you've written, unless there is some periodic condition, which you are not specifying, or all but finitely many $\beta$ are zero, or something like that.

Comment: $i \in [1,2,...,L]$ where L is a constant parameter of the model. e.g. 20.

Comment: So then what does your equation look like for $i=1$? As is it references $x_0$, which you're saying isn't in the problem. Do you have $\beta_1=0$, or $x_0=x_L$, or...?

Comment: oh sorry. For $x_0$ I neglect the second term on RHS.

Comment: Indeed I am open to consider periodic boundary condition . Meaning that $x_{-1}=x_{L}$. However, I think (I could be wrong) that neglecting $x_{-1}$ would make it easier to solve.